# The expression "[System.Version]::Parse('')" cannot be evaluated. Version string portion was too short or too long

Tags: string, error-handling, msbuild, version, system

So,

I keep having this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB4184 The expression "[System.Version]::Parse('')" cannot be evaluated. Version string portion was too short or too long. ...\.nuget\packages\gitinfo\2.2.0\build\GitInfo.targets 218
```

whenever I build/rebuild my solution. After trying to build it several times it runs perfectly but it takes a lot building the solution, so I take like 3 to 5 times more time to build and test my changes.

Here is the error-related code:

```
<Target Name="_EnsureGit">
        <Exec Command='$(GitExe) --version'
              EchoOff='true'
              ContinueOnError='true'
              ConsoleToMSBuild='true'
              StandardErrorImportance='high'
              StandardOutputImportance='low'>
            <Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" PropertyName="_GitOutput"/>
            <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="MSBuildLastExitCode" />
        </Exec>
        <Error Condition="'$(MSBuildLastExitCode)' != '0'" Text="Failed to run `git --version`. Git may not be properly installed: %0A $(_GitOutput)" />

        <PropertyGroup>
            <_GitCurrentVersion>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match("$(_GitOutput)", "\d+\.\d+\.\d+").Value)</_GitCurrentVersion>
        </PropertyGroup>

        <Error Condition="$([System.Version]::Parse('$(_GitCurrentVersion)').CompareTo($([System.Version]::Parse('$(GitMinVersion)')))) &lt; 0"
               Text="Required minimum git version is $(GitMinVersion) but found $(_GitCurrentVersion)." />
</Target>
```

As I said, the error disappears after some tries to build but it's really annoying and time consuming. I reinstalled VS2022, recloned my repo, reinstalled git, deleted the ".nuget" folder but the problem still occurs.

What should I do?

Comment: The error message is showing that the property `$(_GitCurrentVersion)` has no value. Temporarily add some `Message` tasks to display the values of the `$(_GitOutput)` and `$(_GitCurrentVersion)` properties. What are their values when the `Parse()` fails?

Comment: Do we have any more info here ?